# Why does pip upgrade to different versions depending on python version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

On mac, I pulled 4 images 2.9.0, 2.6.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.1 using
`docker run tensorflow/tensorflow:2.9.0-gpu python3 -m pip install -U pip`
and observed the changes in pip version.

- All 4 containers started with pip 20.2.4.
- 2.3.1 and 2.4.0 had python 3.6.9 and their pips were upgraded to 21.3.1
- 2.6.1 and 2.9.0 had python 3.8.10 and their pips were upgraded to 22.2.2

1. Why this difference between 21.3.1 and 22.2.2 when both are using the same `python3 -m pip install -U pip`?
2. How does python version influence pip version?
3. Can 2.3.1 and 2.4.0 tensorflow images have 22.2.2 pip too?
   The 21.3.1 pip causes `ERROR: No matching distribution found for scipy==1.7.3`. It seems to have a smaller
   selection of available scipy packages to install.

I feel like i'm missing some concepts. Could someone introduce them, and some commands to debug/predict what python version will come with/upgrade to what pip version?

**Edit**

I just found a new way of debugging how pip works with verbose flag, so tried `pip install -v scipy==1.7.3` using pip 21.3.1 and found out that different pips refer to the same index at https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/ which houses versions more than 1.5.4, the largest version that pip 21.3.1 was showing as available during `No matching distribution` error.

I initially thought different pip version have access to different portions of the index, and pip 21.3.1 had no way to see scipy 1.7.3. Now it looks like any pip version can see the full list of versions for a package, but the versions have to go through python version compatibility checks to be installed.

The last line from the verbose install was
`Link requires a different Python (3.6.9 not in: '>=3.7'): https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/30/e15b806597e67057e07a5acdc135216ccbf76a5f1681a324533b61066b0b/pip-22.2.2.tar.gz#sha256=3fd1929db052f056d7a998439176d3333fa1b3f6c1ad881de1885c0717608a4b (from https://pypi.org/simple/pip/) (requires-python:>=3.7)`

Not sure why there is a `pip-22.2.2.tar.gz` in the url. Previous lines have earlier pip versions there too, making me think this whole item by item scan not only requires python version to be satisfied, but also the pip version?

**Edit 2**

The last line with pip-22.2.2.tar.gz was a separate search (for pip versions) from the search for scipy versions. I thought the logs from searching list of pip versions were produced from searching the scipy list, that's why i got confused. Scrolling the logs more carefully shows that it searches scipy version first

```
1 location(s) to search for versions of scipy:
 * https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/
```

, then later does

```
1 location(s) to search for versions of pip:
 * https://pypi.org/simple/pip/
```

Comment: Pip 22 doesn't support python 3.6: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#v22-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that Pip 22 doesn't not support python 3.6, so you're getting the latest supported version of pip for your python.

Similarly, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.7.0.html says "This release requires Python 3.7+".

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be thinking that the version of pip decides what version of other packages (in your case `scipy`) are available for installation, but that's not (entirely) true.

All packages can have multiple dependencies, normally they are not depending on pip, but mostly on the python version.

Normally you can see the python dependency on pypi

Example:

> https://pypi.org/project/scipy/1.5.3/ requires `Python >=3.6`
>
> https://pypi.org/project/scipy/1.7.3/ requires `Python >=3.7, <3.11`

pip itself also has python version dependecies, that's why you cannot have pip 22.2.2 on Python 3.6 or lower.

Comment: Could you clarify your `but that's not (entirely) true.`?

I feel it has something to do with the edit in my question, asking about `why there is a pip-22.2.2.tar.gz in the url`. 
My current mental model is that every pip version has access to the full list of packages of a library (eg. https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/  for scipy). Pip will process every single line in that list and check whether python version satisfies the python requirement for each version of scipy. 

What i don't know is whether there is an additional check for the pip version?

Comment: Well, at some point pypi changed all connections to require SSL, so older versions of pip were no longer able to access pypi at all. And some packages may have other dependencies than just the Python version. Some*might* even have a dependency on pip (e.g. if they require a specific version of distutils or the pip tools themself, that's why I added the ``(entirely)``. And yes, pip can "see" all the distributions on pypi, but pip will do it's best to only use distributions available for your python version and your system.

Comment: If you install packages from a requirements file, pip will also try to satisfy cross dependencies. For example, you want to install package A and B and they both depend on package C, but A want C in version range 2-4 and package B requires package C in version range 3-6, then pip will install package C in version 4, because it's the highest version that satisfies both requirements of package A and B.